# How to get return status of ssh command when i use popen() to run ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, pipe, popen, portforwarding

My indent to create reverse ssh tunnel/ssh port forwarding mechanism.

Here is the actual reverse ssh command :

```
ssh -fN -R  101:localhost:22 computer@123.123.0.27 -p 2320
```

I need to run this command from my C api using popen(), i was implemented like as follows.

Note: system's public & private keys are already shared i.e, no need to give the password.

```
int create_tunnel (void)
{
  FILE *fptr_ssh = NULL;
  char sshcmd[100] = {0};
  char response[100] = {0};


  sprintf(sshcmd, "ssh -fN -R  101:localhost:22 computer@123.123.0.27 -p 2320");

  fptr_ssh = popen(sshcmd, "r"); /* Executing ssh */

  if(NULL == fptr_ssh) {
      perror("popen failed");

      return -1;
  }

  /* Getting message from fp */
  if(!fgets(response, (sizeof(response)-1), fptr_ssh)) {
       perror("fgets failed");

       return -1;
  }
  printf("Msg: %s\n", response); 

  pclose(fptr_ssh);

  return 0;
}
```

Success Case: if every thing fine, port forwarding will success no problem.

In Failure Case : Consider this example:
if no connectivity following message will displays in stdout (terminal).

```
ssh: connect to host 123.123.0.27 port 2320: Network is unreachable
```

but i unable to get any information from my C api /fgets() from file pointer fptr_ssh.

It return success and no message from fgets.

```
fgets failed: Success
```